# EOS Unstake Issues on 3 different websites

Tags: unstake

Regarding this account: https://eosflare.io/account/ge2teojsgage
I have tried so many things that are supposed to work, I'm exhausted.

I have the latest versions of both Scatter and SimpleEOS wallets installed, and I'm able to connect with them.

I've tried three sites (both wallets on the first two, and just Scatter on the third):

1. http://eostoolkit.io/account/delegate - when I click undelegate there today - nothing at all happens  I thought I did it there last week, and saw the word "refunding" in at the top, but now I realize it's a heading, not a status, and it says "None" to the right of it.
2. https://www.bloks.io/wallet/resources/unstake - the unstake button turns into a "spinner" when I click it, and still spinning an hour later after I did an errand and came back home.
3. https://eosauthority.com/wallet/undelegate?network=eos - says "Signing transaction" now for over 10 minutes (after I clicked the wallet button to authorize it).

I have tried the full amount (574.3335), and lesser amounts like 570, and even 550.

Part 2: I also just tried to unstake using SimpleEOS, changing staking to 1% from 100%, and got this error, which I'm just now starting to research.
[image]

Maybe I just need to wait till tomorrow and try again?  Did all my failed attempts use up what CPU I had available?  (I also tried the "Refund" function earlier today).

Comment: Same issues for me (gu4damztgege). I have decided to quit EOS completely. Keep my 101.1246 EOS which are due to be refunded 2 months ago! Too much hassle to try and get them back - there are other projects that work as they are supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there welcome to EOSIO!  You need some cpu as the error suggests. Head on over to https://bloks.io/wallet/powerup or https://eospowerup.io/free

Comment: Same error after getting a powerup.  I see the Powerup in the wallet/history.  Do I have to powerup multiple times over days?  Maybe this is why EOS and not taken off the way I expected it would during the prelaunch.  received_cpu_ms: 3   My error says I need 262????

Comment: I don't get it, I have 10 EOS not-staked and a lot more EOS is staked in CPU? Why would I need more? I'm not new, this was from the prelaunch. I got mine done a year ago, but now doing for a friend.

Comment: And further, do not all the wallets report the error correctly, rather than just leaving you hanging?

Comment: one should do it

Comment: Did another power-up.  Message is "Error: assertion failure with message: insufficient staked cpu bandwidth".

Comment: EOSToolkitIO - Unstake gives this Error: assertion failure with message: insufficient staked net bandwidth

Comment: Try using anchor https://greymass.com/en/anchor this will cover the cost of the transaction for you. I see your account, you powered up correctly, not sure why it's not working. https://bloks.io/account/ge2teojsgage, I'm @natpd on Telegram if you like I can try and help there : )

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have started the process.  Now I just wait 3 days.

Comment: Now SimpleEOS Wallet shows still refunding after 4 days.   Balance even says "Will be 1,158.0247 EOS a day ago" (as if it were a future date).   I tried the http://eostoolkit.io/account/refund with that wallet, and got similar error as original reported. I don't see any similar function on Anchor wallet.  How can I force the refund, and why didn't the refund complete by itself?

Comment: Then I tried the refund on the EOSToolkit with Anchor, still got "TRANSACTION HAS FAILED
Error: billed CPU time (241 us) is greater than the maximum billable CPU time for the transaction (0 us)"

Comment: Ok, I tried "Rent Via PowerUp (1 Day)" by CPU, and then retried, and it seems to have been accepted and looks like I can transfer EOS out now.  Wow - what an ordeal!

Comment: welcome to EOS : )